# Rspec: shared examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, dry

I have feature test, which have 2 duplicated parts:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Messages manage" do
  let (:user) { create :user }
  let (:other_user) { create :use }
  before(:each) do
    login_as user
  end

  describe "[message create]" do

    it "messages created by self, should appear on the page", js: true do
      message_text = "Hello my friend"

      visit user_messages_path(user, {with:other_user.id} )
      fill_in :message_body, with: message_text
      click_button t("users.messages.index.send")
      sleep 1 # waiting for js

      page.should have_content(message_text)
      find_field(:message_body).value.should == ""
      page.should have_selector('#message_body', visible: false)
    end

    it "message errors should be displayed", js: true do
      message_text = "123"

      visit user_messages_path(user, {with:other_user.id} )
      fill_in :message_body, with: message_text
      click_button t("users.messages.index.send")
      sleep 1 # waiting for js

      page.should_not have_content("Message: #{message_text}")
      find_field(:message_body).value.should == message_text
      page.should have_selector('.message.error', visible: true)
    end

  end
end
```

What is the best way using of shared_examples or something like that, in this situation? To following DRY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append a specific method right under the code

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Messages manage" do
  # let (:user) { create :user } 
  # Instead expose it as instance variable
  @user = create(:user)
  # let (:other_user) { create :user }
  @other_user = create(:user)
  before(:each) do
    login_as user
  end

  describe "[message create]" do

    it "messages created by self, should appear on the page", js: true do

      # Use the custom method
      send_message "Hello my friend"

      page.should have_content(message_text)
      find_field(:message_body).value.should == ""
      page.should have_selector('#message_body', visible: false)
    end

    it "message errors should be displayed", js: true do

      # Use the custom method
      send_message "123"

      page.should_not have_content("Message: #{message_text}")
      find_field(:message_body).value.should == message_text
      page.should have_selector('.message.error', visible: true)
    end

  end


  def send_message(message_text)
        visit user_messages_path(@user, {with:@other_user.id} )
        fill_in :message_body, with: message_text
        click_button t("@users.messages.index.send")
        sleep 1 # waiting for js
  end

end
```

For more general code, you can extract them into spec/support in a module. But the above method should be good enough for this case.

Comment: one can define the mthod within the appriopriate describe / context block even to keep the interface cleaner.

Comment: Yes, it should be within the block to allow instance variable, I revised that. Just too quick to type answer:) However I think the main describe is the last place to put it, deeper blocks would be too specific.

Comment: depends, i usually give things just the amount of visibility they need, nothing more and since i nest describe and context blocks heavily, it would go down deeper in several cases for me. But that a style choice i guess

Comment: Yes, that's just a style choice. Agreed.

Comment: I'am using exactly the same tehnology like you solution, in my tests.

Comment: @ole, They are not same. My solution extracts the common parts to a function. That's DRY enough for this specific case in my opinion. If you have similar code spreading several tests, you can further extract them to `spec/support`

Comment: Billy, I mean "I use the same tehnology in my real tests". Thanks for you answer.

Comment: I see. Nice to see that :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have quite enough similar code to necessitate a `shared_examples_for` block (though an argument could be made for a utility method in **spec/support/utilities.rb**), so instead I attempted to split it out a bit.

It's difficult to quantitatively give you a right answer for this question as a lot depends on your style of coding, as per the discussion around @BillyChan's answer.  My style is to *attempt* to be as curt yet readable as possible; others may think it's too DRY, some not DRY enough.  Don't know if this actually works as I don't have your code, but for your consideration...

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Message management" do

  let(:user)       { create :user }
  let(:other_user) { create :user }

  before { login_as user }

  subject { page }

  describe "message creation" do
    let(:send_button) { t("users.messages.index.send") }

    before { visit user_messages_path(user, { with: other_user.id }) }

    context "by self", js: true do
      let(:message_text) { "Hello my friend" }

      before do
        fill_in :message_body, with: message_text
        click_button send_button
        sleep 1 # waiting for js
      end

      it { should have_content(message_text) }
      it { should have_selector('#message_body', visible: false) }
      specify { find_field(:message_body).value.should == "" }
    end

    describe "message errors", js: true do
      let(:message_text) { "123" }

      before do
        fill_in :message_body, with: message_text
        click_button send_button
        sleep 1 # waiting for js
      end

      it { should_not have_content("Message: #{message_text}") }
      it { should have_selector('.message.error', visible: true) }
      specify { find_field(:message_body).value.should == message_text }
    end
  end        
end
```

**Edit** Further explanation as requested by @ole:

`specify` is an alias for `it`.  I use `specify` here because I think the phrase reads better (you could just as easily substitute it out for `it`).  Also, the conditions in the `it` blocks relate to the `subject` of `page`, while the content in the `specify` block is essentially not referring directly to the `page` and is "changing the `subject`" of the test.  If I wanted to put the code from the `specify` blocks into what I think is a readable, though a bit more verbose, `it` block, I'd probably change it to something like:

```
describe "message errors", js: true do
  let(:message_text) { "123" }

  before do
    fill_in :message_body, with: message_text
    click_button send_button
    sleep 1 # waiting for js
  end

  it { should_not have_content("Message: #{message_text}") }
  it { should have_selector('.message.error', visible: true) }

  describe "message body value" do
    let(:message_body) { find_field(:message_body).value }
    subject { message_body }
    it { should == message_text }
  end
end
```

You could also remove the `let` statement and put `find_field(:message_body).value` directly into the `subject` block if you wanted.  It's all a matter of taste and style.  Is this syntax appropriate for this example?  You decide :-)

Comment: Paul, could you pls explain: what is the difference using between `it` and `specify` in you solution.

Comment: Okay, further explanation added.